# Is there any way I can use notebook's touchpad as a pressure-aware pointer in a paint program?

Tags: xorg, touchpad, tablet

I have a notebook (ASUS N56VZ) with multitouch touchpad.

Apparently my touchpad supports pressure levels (in Xorg.0.log I have line `synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: pressure range 0 - 255`)

It would great, If I could use the pressure information in paint programs and use it as a poor-man's tablet.

Is it possible at all? If so, what paint programs are supported?